# My anova loop prints out the same results in R

Tags: r, loops, tidyr, anova

My script is designed to run an anova comparison between groups (rows) in each column. It then leads to one data frame that iterates the anova and post-hoc results as well as the name of the column. However, it will continually iterate the same anova and Post-hoc results. How do I fix this? 
[Find a sample sheet here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18mUMXjPW-y5A57XRwPtloJv6sBOmACcT/view?usp=sharing)

```
#Save your Datasheet into variable X
x <- read.csv("T0_B_Class_Anova_test.csv")
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
DF.Anova <- data.frame()
DF.Tukey <- data.frame()
#Counts through the columns
for(i in 2:(ncol(x)-2)){
  columns <- names(x[i])

  ##Runs an ANOVA - Group being a grouping factor
  anovaresult <- anova(aov(x[,2]~Group,data=x))
  DF.Anova <- rbind(DF.Anova, anovaresult)

  ##fix anova into data frame
  Famall = colnames(x)
  Famall = as.data.frame(Famall)
  Famall = Famall[2:52,]
  Famall = as.data.frame(Famall)
  DFanovanames = rep(Famall, each = 2)
  DFanovanames = as.data.frame(DFanovanames)
  #install.packages("tidyr")
  library(tidyr)
  anovanames = data.frame(Names=unlist(DFanovanames, use.names = FALSE))
  o.anovanames = dplyr::arrange(anovanames, Names)
  finalanova_BFT0 = cbind(rn = rownames(DF.Anova), DF.Anova, o.anovanames)

  ##Runs Tukeys Post-hoc test on Anova
  posthocresult <- TukeyHSD(aov(x[,2]~Group,data=x))
  DF.Tukey <- rbind(DF.Tukey, posthocresult$Group)

  ##fix tukey into data frame
  Famname = colnames(x)
  Famname = as.data.frame(Famname)
  Famname = Famname[2:52,]
  Famname = as.data.frame(Famname)
  DFposthocnames = rep(Famname, each = 3)
  DFposthocnames = data.frame(DFposthocnames)
  install.packages("tidyr")
  library(tidyr)
  posthocnames = data.frame(Names=unlist(DFposthocnames, use.names = FALSE))
  o.posthocnames = dplyr::arrange(posthocnames, Names)
  finalposthoc_BFT0 = cbind(rn = rownames(DF.Tukey), DF.Tukey, o.posthocnames)

  ##Prints posthoc results into txt file
  print(columns)
  print(anovaresult)
  print(posthocresult)
}


write.csv(finalanova_BFT0, file="testfinalanova_BCT0.csv")
write.csv(finalposthoc_BFT0, file="finalposthoc_BCT0.csv")
```

Comment: You are not updating `Group` (if the problem is the first `anova`)

Comment: 'Group' never changes, it iterates through each column which contains different bacterial abundances from each individual in 'Group'

Comment: Isn't the problem then `aov(x[,2]` ... Shouldn't it be `x[,i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as advised in [Circle 2: Growing Objects of the R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), avoid expanding complex (higher dimensional) objects like dataframes in a loop. This is memory inefficient and results in excessive copying in RAM.

As for your repeating results, currently your `anova` and `TukeyHSD` formulas never change in each iteration. Specifically, `x[,2]` remains with each iteration:

```
anovaresult <- anova(aov(x[,2]~Group,data=x))

posthocresult <- TukeyHSD(aov(x[,2]~Group,data=x))
```

---

Therefore, consider the following adjustment all using base R that builds a list of dataframes with `lapply` calls and binds test results directly in dataframe. Outside of the loop all dataframes are then appended for one final, singul dataframe.

Below demonstrates using a reproducible, randomized example as GDrive link is not accessible on my end (security) and likely will not be available for future readers. Only adjustment to be made is the sequence of column numbers to be passed into `lapply`.

**Data** *(seeded for reproducibility)*

```
set.seed(061818)
x <- data.frame(
  Group = replicate(500, sample(c("julia", "r", "pandas", "stata", "sas", "spss"), 
                                1, replace=TRUE)),
  NUM1 = rnorm(500) * 100,
  NUM2 = rnorm(500),
  NUM3 = rnorm(500) / 100
)
```

**Dataframe Build**

```
# CREATE LIST OF ANOVA RESULTS DATAFRAME
anova_df_list <- lapply(2:(ncol(x)), function(i){
  ##Runs an ANOVA - Group being a grouping factor
  anovaresult <- anova(aov(x[,i] ~ Group, data=x))

  data.frame(var = names(x[i]),
             type = row.names(anovaresult),
             anovaresult,
             row.names = NULL)
})

# CREATE LIST OF TUKEY HSD RESULTS DATAFRAME
tukey_df_list <- lapply(2:(ncol(x)), function(i){
  ##Runs an ANOVA - Group being a grouping factor
  posthocresult <- TukeyHSD(aov(x[,i] ~ Group, data=x))

  data.frame(var = names(x[i]),
             type = row.names(posthocresult$Group),
             posthocresult$Group,
             row.names = NULL) 
})

# APPEND ALL DFs FOR SINGUL DATAFRAME OUTPUT
finalanova_BFT0 <- do.call(rbind, anova_df_list)

finalposthoc_BFT0 <- do.call(rbind, tukey_df_list)
```

Output

```
finalanova_BFT0

#    var      type  Df       Sum.Sq      Mean.Sq   F.value    Pr..F.
# 1 NUM1     Group   5 3.294895e+04 6.589791e+03 0.5689185 0.7238625
# 2 NUM1 Residuals 494 5.722009e+06 1.158301e+04        NA        NA
# 3 NUM2     Group   5 4.555384e+00 9.110768e-01 1.0519364 0.3864008
# 4 NUM2 Residuals 494 4.278509e+02 8.660949e-01        NA        NA
# 5 NUM3     Group   5 7.930182e-04 1.586036e-04 1.4649269 0.1997531
# 6 NUM3 Residuals 494 5.348403e-02 1.082673e-04        NA        NA

finalposthoc_BFT0

#     var         type          diff           lwr          upr     p.adj
# 1  NUM1 pandas-julia  1.588690e+01 -30.303690269 6.207749e+01 0.9229562
# 2  NUM1      r-julia  6.224191e+00 -39.105049169 5.155343e+01 0.9987890
# 3  NUM1    sas-julia -2.558098e+00 -48.597653093 4.348146e+01 0.9999859
# 4  NUM1   spss-julia -5.533965e-01 -46.743985299 4.563719e+01 1.0000000
# 5  NUM1  stata-julia  1.920475e+01 -29.494409788 6.790390e+01 0.8695383
# 6  NUM1     r-pandas -9.662708e+00 -56.922953435 3.759754e+01 0.9920073
# 7  NUM1   sas-pandas -1.844500e+01 -66.386955838 2.949696e+01 0.8810193
# 8  NUM1  spss-pandas -1.644030e+01 -64.527313252 3.164672e+01 0.9247795
# 9  NUM1 stata-pandas  3.317847e+00 -47.183623854 5.381932e+01 0.9999676
# 10 NUM1        sas-r -8.782289e+00 -55.894929992 3.833035e+01 0.9948026
# 11 NUM1       spss-r -6.777587e+00 -54.037832960 4.048266e+01 0.9985067
# 12 NUM1      stata-r  1.298055e+01 -36.734312824 6.269542e+01 0.9758552
# 13 NUM1     spss-sas  2.004702e+00 -45.937257220 4.994666e+01 0.9999966
# 14 NUM1    stata-sas  2.176284e+01 -28.600522533 7.212621e+01 0.8188459
# 15 NUM1   stata-spss  1.975814e+01 -30.743328824 7.025961e+01 0.8733230
# 16 NUM2 pandas-julia  4.328917e-02  -0.356126828 4.427052e-01 0.9996168
# 17 NUM2      r-julia  7.351585e-02  -0.318451955 4.654837e-01 0.9946513
# 18 NUM2    sas-julia  1.260665e-01  -0.272043455 5.241765e-01 0.9449289
# 19 NUM2   spss-julia  2.112904e-01  -0.188125601 6.107064e-01 0.6557799
# 20 NUM2  stata-julia  2.834413e-01  -0.137666545 7.045492e-01 0.3876287
# 21 NUM2     r-pandas  3.022668e-02  -0.378438781 4.388921e-01 0.9999416
# 22 NUM2   sas-pandas  8.277736e-02  -0.331782960 4.973377e-01 0.9928376
# 23 NUM2  spss-pandas  1.680012e-01  -0.247813441 5.838159e-01 0.8573913
# 24 NUM2 stata-pandas  2.401522e-01  -0.196540570 6.768449e-01 0.6165912
# 25 NUM2        sas-r  5.255068e-02  -0.354838417 4.599398e-01 0.9991049
# 26 NUM2       spss-r  1.377745e-01  -0.270890910 5.464400e-01 0.9288895
# 27 NUM2      stata-r  2.099255e-01  -0.219965388 6.398164e-01 0.7288549
# 28 NUM2     spss-sas  8.522386e-02  -0.329336457 4.997842e-01 0.9918030
# 29 NUM2    stata-sas  1.573748e-01  -0.278123725 5.928734e-01 0.9063874
# 30 NUM2   stata-spss  7.215095e-02  -0.364541797 5.088437e-01 0.9970600
# 31 NUM3 pandas-julia  2.540117e-03  -0.001925601 7.005835e-03 0.5807914
# 32 NUM3      r-julia -1.418724e-03  -0.005801167 2.963718e-03 0.9396929
# 33 NUM3    sas-julia -9.892923e-04  -0.005440408 3.461824e-03 0.9882722
# 34 NUM3   spss-julia  2.222945e-04  -0.004243423 4.688012e-03 0.9999918
# 35 NUM3  stata-julia  2.480217e-04  -0.004460225 4.956269e-03 0.9999892
# 36 NUM3     r-pandas -3.958842e-03  -0.008527974 6.102912e-04 0.1323856
# 37 NUM3   sas-pandas -3.529410e-03  -0.008164451 1.105631e-03 0.2496801
# 38 NUM3  spss-pandas -2.317823e-03  -0.006966888 2.331242e-03 0.7109641
# 39 NUM3 stata-pandas -2.292096e-03  -0.007174591 2.590399e-03 0.7607515
# 40 NUM3        sas-r  4.294318e-04  -0.004125430 4.984294e-03 0.9998066
# 41 NUM3       spss-r  1.641019e-03  -0.002928114 6.210151e-03 0.9086036
# 42 NUM3      stata-r  1.666746e-03  -0.003139700 6.473192e-03 0.9204005
# 43 NUM3     spss-sas  1.211587e-03  -0.003423454 5.846628e-03 0.9757341
# 44 NUM3    stata-sas  1.237314e-03  -0.003631829 6.106457e-03 0.9785797
# 45 NUM3   stata-spss  2.572720e-05  -0.004856768 4.908222e-03 1.0000000
```

Comment: This worked absolutely PERFECTLY. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Haha...Glad to help. That's my name *Parfait* (French for *Perfect*)...lol. Happy coding!